# Php multidimenson array sort (different keys)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Okay, i got an Array of Arrays with diferent keys:

```
$update = Array(
        "123456" => Array ( "Miguel, Gorila",12,4),
        "3300221713" => Array ( "Miguel, Macaco",6,2),
        String => Array (String, INTa, INTb)
        );
```

I want to sort by INTa and then by INTb. I know i need to have a compare function, but i don't figure how to get the value when all the keys are diferent.

```
function cmp(array $a, array $b) {
    return $a[][1] - $b[][1];
}
usort($update, cmp);
```

Should be something like this to sort by the INTa, and how can i make it sorted by both?

Comment: Also, if you want to preserve your keys in the top level array, you will want to use `uasort` or else the top level array will be re-indexed. "**U**ser defined, **A**ssociative array **sort**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a multi-key sort, you need to have a compound comparison:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $x = $a[1] - $b[1];
    if ($x)  return $x;
    return $a[2] - $b[2];
}
```